# Getting UnmatchedTypeException while converting wsdl to java

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to convert the wdsl to java by using axis2 script wsdl2java.sh and getting the following exception

```
        Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the name OTRS_SessionCreate with namespace http://172.22.1.76/TicketConnector/
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
    Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the name OTRS_SessionCreate with namespace http://172.22.1.76/TicketConnector/
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:537)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:282)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the name OTRS_SessionCreate with namespace http://172.22.1.76/TicketConnector/
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.TypeMappingAdapter.getTypeMappingName(TypeMappingAdapter.java:82)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.getInputParamElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:3011)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.getInputElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2793)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.generateMethodElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2358)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.loadOperations(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2242)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.createDOMDocumentForCallbackHandler(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1232)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.writeCallBackHandlers(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1198)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:500)
        ... 3 more
```

and the following is the wsdl file ,please guys really need help at this one trying to integrate otrs ,using this [file](https://code.google.com/p/otrs-git/source/browse/development/webservices/GenericTicketConnector.wsdl?r=d3d40956d413643d48d0dcbf8c4bdede60102408) for generating the stubs

plase do help me in this 
thanks